# (KeyError) I want to make an application using models and ModelForm structure in Django but I am getting keyerror error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, keyerror

I'm trying to make an electrical formula calculation app in Django. I want to enter the values ​​in the variables in the calculation page and see them on the results page. In doing so, I want the modules to be interconnected because to reach the values.

*views.py*

```
class CalculationView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        transformers = Transformer.objects.all()
        
        form = CalculationForm()
        return render(request, 'calculation_form.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = CalculationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            

            LowVoltageLineCurrent = data['Power'] / (data['HighVoltage'] * math.sqrt(3))
            HighVoltageLineCurrent = data['Power'] / (data['LowVoltage'] * math.sqrt(3))

            if data['LVconnection'].lower() == 'y':
                LowVoltagePhaseCurrent = LowVoltageLineCurrent
            elif data['LVconnection'].lower() == 'd':
                LowVoltagePhaseCurrent = LowVoltageLineCurrent / math.sqrt(3)
            else:
                LowVoltagePhaseCurrent = None

            if data['HVconnection'].lower() == 'y':
                HighVoltagePhaseCurrent = HighVoltageLineCurrent
            elif data['HVconnection'].lower() == 'd':
                HighVoltagePhaseCurrent = HighVoltageLineCurrent / math.sqrt(3)
            else:
                HighVoltagePhaseCurrent = None

            transformer = data['transformer']
            

            result = Result.objects.create(
                Power=data['Power'],
                HighVoltage=data['HighVoltage'],
                LowVoltage=data['LowVoltage'],
                LowVoltageLineCurrent=LowVoltageLineCurrent,
                HighVoltageLineCurrent=HighVoltageLineCurrent,
                LVconnection=data['LVconnection'],
                HVconnection=data['HVconnection'],
                LowVoltagePhaseCurrent=LowVoltagePhaseCurrent,
                HighVoltagePhaseCurrent=HighVoltagePhaseCurrent,
                transformer=transformer,
                user=request.user
            )

            return redirect('results', pk=result.pk)

        return render(request, 'calculation_form.html', {'form': form})


class ResultsView(View):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        result = Result.objects.get(pk=pk, user=request.user)
        return render(request, 'results.html', {'result': result})
```

*models.py*

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Transformer(models.Model):
    LV_CHOICES = [('D', 'D'),('Y', 'Y'),]
    HV_CHOICES = [('D', 'D'),('Y', 'Y'),]

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Power = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    HighVoltage = models.IntegerField()
    HVconnection = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=HV_CHOICES, default='D', db_index=True)
    LowVoltage = models.IntegerField()
    LVconnection = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LV_CHOICES, default='D', db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Result(models.Model):
    transformer = models.ForeignKey(Transformer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="transformer_result")
    HighVoltageLineCurrent = models.FloatField()    
    HighVoltagePhaseCurrent = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    LowVoltageLineCurrent = models.FloatField()
    LowVoltagePhaseCurrent = models.FloatField()
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from .models import Transformer


class CalculationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Transformer
        fields='__all__'
```

line 52, in post
**    transformer = data['transformer']
~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'transformer'
**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTqnM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3NXV.png)

to the calculation form
fields = ['transformer']
I tried adding or removing it but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Your `Transformer` model has no `transformer` field...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line

```
transformer = data["transformer"]
```

Becsuse calculation_form.html does not have any key named transformer.

As far a I understood you need to create a object name transformer and pass it to result page.

you should create transformer object like this.

```
LowVoltageLineCurrent = data['Power'] / (data['HighVoltage'] * math.sqrt(3))
HighVoltageLineCurrent = data['Power'] / (data['LowVoltage'] * math.sqrt(3))

transformer = Transformer()

if data['LVconnection'].lower() == 'y':
    transformer.LowVoltagePhaseCurrent = LowVoltageLineCurrent
elif data['LVconnection'].lower() == 'd':
    transformer.LowVoltagePhaseCurrent = LowVoltageLineCurrent / math.sqrt(3)
else:
    transformer.LowVoltagePhaseCurrent = None
if data['HVconnection'].lower() == 'y':
    transformer.HighVoltagePhaseCurrent = HighVoltageLineCurrent
elif data['HVconnection'].lower() == 'd':
    transformer.HighVoltagePhaseCurrent = HighVoltageLineCurrent / math.sqrt(3)
else:
    transformer.HighVoltagePhaseCurrent = None
transformer.save()
```